# how do I get a response from a node.js webapp in my javascript webpage

Tags: javascript, mysql, node.js

EDIT:
How can I get a response from my node.js webapp service (code sample#2) after i click a button on a javascript web page (code sample #1). the alert is blank and i would expect the request.responsetext to show up.

I am working on a site that uses a website for viewing particular videos which sends the info after viewing to a web app being written in node.js.

The web app in node.js will based on the url sent either update the database or return in xml format listings of the database.

The registration company accesses the node.js app directing via internet and gets there info just fine.

The main issue I am having is in the website that video is viewed is after the user presses a button and the web page updating the database is getting a response so I can make sure database was updated.

code sample  #1 ( from the website end users are on)

The url sent would look like this `http://xxxctdb.yyyyy.com:1337/?c=u&r=3&s=c&id=cry12011999last46`

Then I press a button on the page the function submitclick() is fired and the request is sent. once the readystate=4 then the button goes away and I want an alert to display the response whether it be good, or bad or just the word 'thanks'.

```
<script>
        function submitclick() {

            var request = new XMLHttpRequest();

            request.onreadystatechange = function () {
                if (request.readyState == 4 ) {
                    var div = document.getElementById('Button');
                    div.style.display = 'none';
                    alert (request.responseText);
                }


            };
    request.open("GET", "Http://xxxctdb.yyyyyy.com:1337?c=u&r="+getQueryVariable("r")+"&s=c&id="+getQueryVariable("id"), true);
    request.send();

}
    </script>
```

Code sample #2 (the node.js with irrelevant code removed ie.. many other cases under switch)

```
var mysql = require('mysql');
var express = require('express');
var routes = require('./routes');
var http = require('http');
var path = require('path');
var o2x = require('object-to-xml');
var app = express();
var pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit : 100, //important
    host     : 'localhost',
    user     : '',
    password : '',
    database : '',
    debug    : false
});

// all environments
app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
app.set('views', path.join(__dirname, 'views'));
app.set('view engine', 'jade');
app.use(express.favicon());
app.use(express.logger('dev'));
app.use(express.json());
app.use(express.urlencoded());
app.use(express.methodOverride());
app.use(app.router);
app.use(require('stylus').middleware(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, 'public')));

// development only
if ('development' == app.get('env')) {
    app.use(express.errorHandler());
}


http.createServer(app).listen(app.get('port'), function () {
    console.log('Express server listening on port ' + app.get('port'));
});
function handle_database(req, res) {
    console.log(req.query.r);
    console.log(req.query.id);
    pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
        if (err) {
            connection.release();
            res.json({ "code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database" });
            return;
        }

        console.log('connected as id ' + connection.threadId);
        switch (req.query.c) {

            case "u":

                var post = { ID: req.query.id, VIDEO: req.query.r, Status: req.query.s };

                connection.query('INSERT INTO contest SET ?', post, function (err, result) {



                    connection.release();
                    if (!err) {
                        console.log("insert ID "+ result.insertID)
                        console.log("command " + req.query.c);
                        console.log("video " + req.query.r);
                        console.log("ID " + req.query.id);
                        console.log("Status " + req.query.s);
                        console.log("Referer " + req.headers.referer);
                        console.log(o2x({
                            '?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?' : null,
                            Results: {
                                Inserts: result
                            }
                        }));
                        res.json("help");

                    }
                });
                break;
            default:
                res.json({ "code" : 1000, "status" : "Error command line" });
        }


        connection.on('error', function (err) {
            res.json({ "code" : 100, "status" : "Error in connection database" });
            return;
        });
    });
}

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    -
handle_database(req, res);

});

app.listen(3000);
```

Comment: Not quite sure what your question actually is? Also, please re-read your question and edit it so that it actually makes sense. From your name I would suppose you're a native english speaker, please make the effort to have intelligible questions.

Comment: jcaron, thanks for your comment and hopefully what i added helps, on another note please do not bring nationality into this, just because i may be an English speaker doesn't mean my English writing skills are the best. i could just as easily assume that you not being from US that you cannot understand English that is not perfect. But I won't. my question makes perfect sense to me, if you want clarification on something then let me know. I wrote a lot because it seems many people complain there is not enough info, or not enough code

Comment: If you're not willing to make an effort to write an intelligible question, don't be surprised if nobody is willing to make an effort to decipher it. Your question has nearly no capitalisation or punctuation, which makes it very hard to follow. Help people understand your issue, and you're a lot more likely to get answers. On your question, have you checked that you do indeed go through the path on your server that should return something (i.e. there was no error)? Client-side, have you checked the status code on the response?

Comment: @jcaron, thanks. Yes, I do know that I do indeed go through the path on the server that should return something. If you look at sample #2 , right after `case "u":` all is executing. If put the URL that the website is using directly in a browser, I do get the response of "help". on the client side i will check the status code. I thought i was checking the status code when looking at `request.readyState` in sample 1, which i know its reaching because the button turns off

Comment: it appears `request.status` = 0

Comment: Have you checked logs? You are aware that in the general case, you cannot make an Ajax request to a different domain from the one hosting the page running the code, right?